# Updating the record on click of edit icon in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

Iam trying to implement CRUD operations on Gallery items in PowerApps

[image]

Above given is the screenshot of the page which displays All Passport Details.

Here onclick of the + icon on the right corner I am able to navigate to "New_Edit_Passport" screen as shown below to add new record

[image]

But when I click the edit Icon I need to update the record in the same screen with the selected record values present in the form .

To achieve that I tried

> If(IsBlank(Gallery1.Selected),Defaults(Passport_Details),(Gallery1.Selected))

But its giving me update form on click of the + icon also

kindly guide me how to update the form with the selected record on click of the edit icon placed in that particular record

Comment: Can you share with us the code in both buttons?